# Vba import emails from shared mailbox on Outlook to excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Can you please help me with this code? I need to know the total emails received by the shared mailbox. My code works smoothly but only shows the count of unread emails on inbox. I want it to show read and unread both.

Please see below for code:

```
Sub getDataFromOutlook()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace =    OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner =  OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com")
objOwner.Resolve

If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set Folder =     OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
End If

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items

    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_ReceiptDate").Value Then

        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Body
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

        i = i + 1

    End If

 Next OutlookMail

 Set Folder = Nothing
 Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
 Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does not do anything with read vs unread emails - it simply imports all emails newer than some value in your spreadsheet.